# How to make a button on a table view cell call the correct tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a button that is part of a custom UITableViewCell. What I want is that when someone clicks the button, that the proper tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to be called for that cell.

How do I tie the button to the proper cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Any suggestions and / or code samples will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the indexPath from the touch event. Modify your buttonTapped method to be this:

```
- (void) buttonTapped:(id) sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and then use something like the following:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:tableView]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one section, you can probably use `UIView`'s `tag` property.

Something like follows would theoretically work.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)idxPath 
{
    Your_UITableViewCell_Subclass * cell = [tableView dequeueCellWithIdentifier:@"..."];
    cell.button.tag = idxPath.row;

    ....

    return cell;
}

....

- (void) buttonTapped:(id) sender 
{
    int idx = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    NSIndexPath * idxPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:idxPath];

    // Do whatever you want to do with the cell
}
```

Comment: This solution won't handle more than one section.